# User input inside a function - I can't get my program to recognize the input

Tags: python

I searched and I couldn't find anything. I need help being able to have the user enter for those inputs and then return the difference. So I thought that when I prompted for the input it would actually save those input that the users entered. However, it won't even prompt for the input. Then I am trying to get the price of the product to be multiple by .05 to calculate the true total.

(a * .05) - b       ?

Thanks for the help

```
def differenceofTwoNumbers(a, b):
return a - b


  a = float(raw_input("Price of product")
  b = float(raw_input("Payment amount"))

total = (a - b
print(difference)
```

Comment: The example code you've posted is filled with indentation errors, as such, it is impossible to diagnose what is going. Can you fix the indentation to accurately reflect the code you are actually running?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this because it seems like you at least *tried* something, even though you've got some pretty drastic issues in your function definition, including, but not limited to basic syntax errors (unclosed parentheses, messed up indentations...)

However, in the future, **try to debug your code *at least* a minimum before posting it**

Let's walk through what's wrong with your code:

```
def differenceofTwoNumbers(a, b):
return a - b
```

The above, if indented properly, would return `a-b` if you name those arguments in your function call:

```
def differenceofTwoNumbers(a, b):
    return a - b

>>> differenceofTwoNumbers(5,3)
2
```

However, you seem like you're trying to redefine `a` and `b` based on your user input. So you don't need to pass any arguments to your function. In this case, do something like this:

```
def differenceofTwoNumbers():
  a = float(input("Price of product: "))
  b = float(input("Payment amount: "))
  return((a*0.5) - b)
```

Which will run the way you want it (I think)

```
>>> differenceofTwoNumbers()
Price of product: 10
Payment amount: 3
2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You had made many mistakes

here is the corrected code

```
def differenceofTwoNumbers(a, b):
    return a*0.5 - b


a = float(raw_input("Price of product"))
b = float(raw_input("Payment amount"))

print(differenceofTwoNumbers(a,b))
```